xray license expiration api call
Using JFrog Artifactory with Xray.
Trying to get xray license info about the expiration date via curl, but /xray/api/v1/license/status only gives what type of license and no other info
ex:
{"status":"Enterprise"}
xray_version":"3.67.9"
Anyone able to get more info about the Xray license using API? all other calls give 404 page not found or the same output just showing "Enterprise"
/xray/api/v1/updates/getStatus
/xray/api/v1/license
/xray/api/v1/reports/licenses
/api/system/configuration/reverseProxy/nginx
/api/system/configuration/webServer
/xray/api/system
/api/system
/xray/api/v1/xraylicense
/xray/api/v2/xraylicense
/rest/raven/2.0/api/xraylicense
/xray/api/system/license


According to this KB it is the expected behavior if you are not using a trial license.
Also, if you are not using a trial license, since Artifactory 7.x and Xray 3.x, the license for Xray is integrated into the Artifactory license so the expiration date for the Xray license is the same as the ARtifactory license

Thanks adi_m that's where i got the first working end point... was just hoping to get more data out of it
